# Хостинг изображений с api

Tags: android, хостинг-изображений

Нужен бесплатный (для коммерческого использования) хостинг изображений с api для android. Если таких нету, тогда посоветуйте пожалуйста хостинг с хорошим бесплатным тарифом.

Comment: imgur ? Вроде бесплатно.

Comment: @Hardc0re да, думал о нем, но боюсь кое-чего. Что, если начнется спам просмотров изображений (не уверен, что такое бывает, но вдруг)? Там на загрузку с их сервера тоже ограничение есть в месяц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase позволяет хранить до 10 Гбайт - https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
Отличное API, лёгкая интеграция, поддержка любых платформ.

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: благодарю) очень полезно